# informações para criação de apk

Tags: php, app

EDITADO: desenvolvendo um app que precisa se comunicar com um servidor externo com transferencia de informações "cadastros/informações privadas", preciso do php para manter a segurança como se faz num site de compra/vendas online?

Comment: Precisamos de mais informações. A compreensão do seu tópico está difícil, portanto, vou dizer apenas o que entendi disso tudo.
Você está desenvolvendo um aplicativo, e esse aplicativo está sendo desenvolvido para Android. Esse aplicativo vai se comunicar um servidor. Você citou o PHP. 
Agora quando pergunta que o mesmo vai ter que estar localizado servidor, está falando somente do aplicativo em PHP certo?

Comment: Segurança é algo genérico de mais, existem vários pontos de segurança. Qual sua preocupação e qual é o seu problema em especifico? Está preocupado com armazenamento de dados no lado do cliente ou com a segurança no armazenamento de dados no lado do servidor? Ou está preocupado com a segurança da transferência de dados entre o servidor e o cliente? Se for a comunicação entre o aplicativo e o servidor utilize TLS, tenha um certificado longo e válido e o aplicativo verifica a chave publica do teu servidor. Isso minimante garante autenticidade e confidencialidade.

Comment: @Inkeliz você me ajudou muito com esta informação de TLS obrigado, mas tambem tenho a dúvida sobre, se devo utilizar PHP dentro do servidor ou não é necessario a fim de manter segurança?

Comment: @FelipeO.Ribeiro até onde eu saiba não ha como usar PHP no cliente, mas enfim. Se quer que fique "a prova de engenharia reversa" o PHP no servidor para obter/enviar  informações seria melhor. Porque no cliente qualquer engenharia reversa revelaria o funcionado do aplicativo. Se usar o PHP (ou qualquer outra linguagem para o servidor) o máximo que revelaria é como as comunicações são feitas. Tenha o aplicativo "Prisma" como exemplo, o servidor processava todas as modificações na foto, fazer engenharia reversa não revelaria como as fotos são alteradas, pois essas são feitas de fato fora do app.

Comment: @Inkeliz eu tambem sei sobre a questão do PHP ser somente útilizavel no servidor, mas tu sancionaste a minha dúvida, que era o fate de ser melhor utilizar o mesmo para a transição de informação, obrigado pela ajuda e se tiver algum método de reconhecimento do tipo de classificação ou algo assim aqui no forum, favor me avise.